# Not able to set font-size: 12px in ant-design components & also not able to apply a custom google fonts to ant-design components

Tags: sass, antd

How we can get applied 12px font size to ant-design components, if i am trying to provide a 10px font-size to a label, in styles section it shows that it has been applied, but if i hover that element using inspector tool, it shows me 13px, like it automatically sets that font-size to 13px
[image]

Also please let me know how we can apply google fonts in ant-design for all components.
just FYI, using sass/scss files for styling.

Wanted to know how we can achieve to apply 12px font-size in ant-design ?
& How we can apply google font-family in ant-design components ?

I will be glad if you can guide me here, already wasted a day to dig into this.